# Component rendering twice when called outside switch, inside router. Not using strictmode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my Router component. I'm returning a routeless Component on top of my switch so it renders over top of every route. On initial load of the app (only initial load, not when rerouting), it renders < Component /> twice. It's a functional component that's just returning another component, based on a condition. I'm not using .strictMode.

My App.js is just returning RouterApp wrapped in ThemeProvider from styled-components.

Why is this rendering twice?

```
const RouterApp = (props) => {

  const renderPublicRoute = (path, ComponentToRender, exact = true) => {
    return (
      <Route
        exact={exact}
        path={path}
        render={props => <ComponentToRender {...props} />}
      />
    );
  }


  return (
    <Router>
      <Component />     *<---the culprit*
      <Switch>
        {renderPublicRoute('/path', OnboardingScreen)}
        {renderPublicRoute('/anotherpath', TermsScreen)}
         ....etc..etc...
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default RouterApp;
```

Comment: Why is rerendering a problem? Components will rerender when there is change in Props, State or Context values. To skip rerendering, you can use `React.memo`.

Comment: Feel free to create a minimal & complete code example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
Could you provide an example on how to setup React.memo? I tried this based on the docs and it didn't work.
It's an issue here because I need to make a route vs previous route check and when it re-renders, it updates the previous route to be the same as the current and then the check fails.

Comment: I tried to, but could not reproduce this issue. `Component` is rendering only once. It is not re-rendering when I go back and forth between `/path` and `/anotherpath`.